# Повышение приоритета процедуры

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Подскажите, пожалуйста, могу ли я программно, в PL/SQL коде (и при вызове) процедуры каким - то образом повлиять на приоритет ее выполнения? Скажем повысить, чтобы она выполнялась в первую очередь, а другие процессы (процедуры) ждали?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. Могли бы вы привести пример, где этот вопрос возник?

Comment: В определенные моменты на сервере запускаются несколько процедур, которые конкурируют за ресурсы. Можно ли как-то программно сделать, чтобы одна из этих процедур всегда имела приоритет над другими?

Comment: Мой вопрос остаётся открытым. Где или в связи с чем этот вопрос возник? Речь идёт о jobs?

Comment: С нехваткой ресурсов сервера ))) Есть критичная процедура, которая начинает выполняться поздно, когда сервер уже вовсю "молотит" и ей приходится ждать то освобождения ресурсов, то своей очереди. А хотелось бы ее как-то протолкнуть и сделать, чтобы в первую очередь выполнялась она. Хоть теоретически такое возможно? )))

Comment: Это процедура, которая запускает задачи (jobs). На уровне задач как-то можно управлять приоритетом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, перечитайте ваш вопрос и комментарии. Войдите в положение того, кто не знаком ни со средой выполнения ваших  приложений, ни с самими приложениями. Например - _когда сервер уже вовсю "молотит"_ сервер это десятки процессов, какой из них "молотит", или все "молотят"?  Пока ясно одно - не хватает ресурсов, то надо их добавить.